Создание select запроса
только начала изучение clickHouse. Нужно сделать выборки всех уникальных eventType у которых более 1000 событий
[![CREATE TABLE events (
eventID Int64,
eventType String,
userID Int64,
eventTime DateTime,
payload String
) ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY (eventID, eventTime);
/*Выборки всех уникальных eventType у которых более 1000 событий
*/
SELECT eventID, count(*) as c
FROM events
WHERE c >:1000
group by eventID,eventType ;]1]1

Если прям в лоб решать, группировать по событиям, где в группировке более 1000, показать.
SELECT eventType
FROM events
GROUP BY eventType
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1000


спасибо огромное)
